# Конфликт IP DHCP

Tags: ip, dhcp

В DHCP сети предприятия один из компьютеров не работает - конфликт IP адресов. Все началось с того, что компьютеру поменяли матку. Особенность в том, что компьютер не работает именно в этой подсети, в другой все обычно. Винду переустановил, ошибка сохранилась. Другие компьютеры в порядке. Есть подозрения на аппаратную ошибку новой матки. Еще вариант - совпадение mac, но в настройках **82579lm** сменить его нельзя. Что это может быть и как локализовать неисправность?

Comment: Проблема крылась в совпадающих MAC! XD

Comment: значит поменять можно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну я предлагаю через tcpdump вычислить ту машину у которой ip дублируется.Ну и зарубить ее фаерволом )) по маку. А виновник сам потом прибежит. У нас были такие случаи когда какой нибудь умник статично забивает себе ip.

Answer (score 0):

Поменяйте мак на одной из машин. В крайнем случае поставьте дополнительную сетевую карту - будет новый мак :)